# Location Listener is not running my onLocationChanged

Tags: java, android, android-location, locationlistener

My buildLocationEvent(location) in onLocationChanged never runs? Is there a particular reason why this would be? I can see no reason, perhaps I am missing somethig obvious, please advise me what is going wrong here and how i can sort this so i can start to get the location data out properly.

I have copied the code below:

```
public class LService extends Service {

    public static final String TAG = "Lervice";
    private LocationListener listener;
    private LocationManager manager;
    private static LocationEvent locationEvent = new LocationEvent();


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startMyOwnForeground();

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                buildLocationEvent(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        manager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.app.myapp";
        String channelName = "LService";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(3, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(manager != null){
            manager.removeUpdates(listener);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public void buildLocationEvent(Location location){
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        double[] coordinate = {latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude};
        locationEvent.setCoordinate(coordinate);
        locationEvent.setAltitude(location.getAltitude());
        locationEvent.setHorizontalAccuracy(location.getAccuracy());
        locationEvent.setVerticalAccuracy(location.getVerticalAccuracyMeters());
        locationEvent.setTimestamp(location.getTime());
        sendLocationToManager(locationEvent);
    }

    private void sendLocationToManager(LocationEvent locationEvent){
        Intent intent = new Intent("locationCreated");
        sendLocalBroadcastEvent(intent, locationEvent);
    }

    private void sendLocalBroadcastEvent(Intent intent, LocationEvent locationEvent){
        intent.putExtra("locationevent", locationEvent);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help on this. If you need anything clarifying please let me know.

Permissions are called in Main when i run:

```
String[] appPermissions = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
    };
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1240;


        //get permissions for location
        Log.d(TAG, "permissions: "+ checkAndRequestPermissions()); //false

        if(true) {

            //I RUN MY CODE HERE
        }

    }


    private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String perm : appPermissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(perm);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
            );
            return false;
        }
        //All Permissions granted
        return true;
    }
```

Hope that helps.

This is how i start the service:

```
    public void startUpdatingLocation(){
        //Start sensor service
        Intent locationIntent = new Intent(MyApplication.getAppContext(), LService.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            MyApplication.getAppContext().startForegroundService(locationIntent);
        } else {
            MyApplication.getAppContext().startService(locationIntent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possibly a permission issue - which API version - background services have a new permission type in API 29, ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

Comment: @Andy Thanks,  When i run the app first time it does ask for location permissions which i grant all the time. Then run again it doesnt ask again and runs with the notification to allow background. I have just tested, the location gets returned on the emulator but not on my phone! so you maybe right, any ways i can fix this?

Comment: Added the permissions request in main to the question.

Comment: I am calling sensor data and location data would it be an issue if they are not called on seperate threads?

Comment: are you not getting location data only first time or every time?

Comment: Not getting it at all on phone but do get it on emulator

Comment: Just added the call to start the service to the question if helpful

Comment: This line seems to cause an issue:              manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, listener);
  if gives me a permissions error, if i supress it i get location data on the emulator! if i surround with a permissions check i get no location data on either emulator or phone?

Comment: Super strange behaviour if i uninstall the app then run the app on the phone it immedialty asks for location permission if i press the allow quickly the app still crashes however the location service is running in the background i can see the data on logcat. if i then restart the app i only see sensor data output on loogcat no location anymore? Any ideas

Comment: So i put the two service calls sensor and location on to two seperate asynctasks, which meant they were now coming through. However now the main callback which was on a 1 second delay is not being called!!! this was being called prior to this change?